# apply shopping cart price rule programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

i have created three rule on `customer group`.

> 1. 25% off
> 2. 35% off
> 3. 45% off

I want to do some calculation and apply one rule. Can any give me idea about that?

*Note: cannot use coupon code.*

Comment: Do you check this http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/

Comment: they are using coupon code that will not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing some research if cannot find solution for that  so then i change the shopping cart price rule to `customer group`

i create three customer group

> 1. basic 25% off
> 2. silver 35% off
> 3. gold 45% off

when user login using this event do my calculation and change the customer group. it worked for me.

```
<frontend>
     <events>
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <partners>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>partners/observer</class>
                        <method>customerLogin</method>
                    </partners>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
        </events>
    </frontend>
```